# Trying to Find MAX value of a SUM query in SQL

Tags: sql, join, sum, max, teradata

I have 2 tables:

```
Product(ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice, VendorID, CategoryID)

SoldVia(ProductID, TID, NoOfItems)
```

I need to display the productID for the product that has been sold in the highest quantity. I can easily come up with the list sorted in ascending order with this query:

```
SELECT distinct productid, sum(noofitems)
From soldvia
Group By productid
Order By sum(noofitems) DESC
```

By question is, how do I only show the top value of the list, using the `MAX` function? I can't use `LIMIT` or `TOP` for this assignment, but whenever I use `MAX`, I run into various issues with aggregates.

After I'm done with that, how do I show the product name for the best selling product?

Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` is almost never necessary.

Comment: Turn your query into a derived table by making it a subquery with an alias.  Then select the max from the derived table.

Comment: @DanBracuk, can you give me a snippet of what SELECT and WHERE would look like for these 2 specific tables?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT prd.ProductId
FROM Product prd
INNER JOIN SoldVia sld ON prd.ProductId = sld.ProductId
WHERE prd.NoOfItems = (SELECT MAX(NoOfItems) FROM SoldVia) -- Check for item that has max # items sold
```

This will return the items with the highest aggregate value of `NoOfItems`

**Update**

I didn't know you were on Teradata.  That makes life much much easier :)

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM Product prd
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ProductId, SUM(NoOfItems) AS TotalItemsSold
  FROM SoldVia
  GROUP BY ProductId
  QUALIFY RANK() OVER(ORDER BY TotalItemsSold DESC) = 1 -- Only return ProductId(s) with largest TotalItemsSold value (includes ties)
) agg ON prd.ProductId = agg.ProductId -- Get aggregate # items sold (if any)
```

This will only return rows if there are matching rows in both tables.

Comment: Teradata returns - [3809] Column 'ProductId' is ambiguous.

Comment: Oops...both tables have that field.  Just qualify the reference -- see updated above.  Or you can just replace it with ProductName, if that's the only field you want.

Comment: Ran and got - [3810] Column/Parameter 'DB_JUKIC_ZAGIMORE.prd.NoOfItems' does not exist. I think Teradata has issues recognizing alias, but even after I got rid of them and spelled all table names out, it still said that "product.noofitems" after WHERE didn't exist in the database

Comment: Sorry, I think my original query is not correct.  It only checked for the MAX(NoOfItems) value, not the aggregate.  See my updated query above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more simple, but I think this still should work for you

```
select productid, max(itemsum) 
from
(SELECT productid, sum(noofitems) as itemsum
FROM soldvia
group by productid)
;
```

Comment: This might work in old MySQL versions, but in no other DBMS.

Comment: Teradata spits out [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between ')' and ';'. , but I think out of all responses you're the one who probably is the closest to the real answer (if there is one)

Comment: To get rid of the syntax error you have to add `as agg`to the subselect. But then you'll get `3504 Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.`. If you you add the grouping, you end up just doing the aggregation twice and not getting the result restricted to ovrerall max.

Comment: @SQLdumbo: It's not close because it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ravioli's answer, without a subselect.

From logic I would prefer the subselect (early reducing the number of rows), but the explain shows, that 1 more step is used with the subselect. I expect it to be different for larger number of rows.

```
select
    S.ProductID
    , P.ProductName
    , sum(NoOfItems) as TotalItemsSold
from SoldVia as S
inner join Product as P
    on S.ProductID = P.ProductID
group by S.ProductID, P.ProductName
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(ORDER BY TotalItemsSold DESC) = 1 -- Only return ProductId(s) with largest TotalItemsSold
;
```

Comment: One step less doesn't mean *more efficient* :-) @ravioli's answer will aggregate & filter first and then join to one product row (maybe a few rows), but this will join all all products first and then aggregate/filter. Sometimes the optimizer is smart enough to apply *early aggregation* but probably not in this case.

Comment: @dnoeth I fully aggree. Just wanted to add it as way to let the optimizer choosing his own way instead of forcing him to follow my thoughts. At least it is worth to give it a try, especially with large numbers and complex situations. In my experience he is quite smart, only sometimes I can beat him.